# libiconv for AIX 5.3

Tags: encoding, aix, iconv

I need to use iconv in 1 of my app running on AIX 5.3. I googled for some RPM sites for AIX and could not see libiconv for AIX 5.3. Can anybody point to correct RPM repository?  I assume
it is not a good practice to use libiconv for AIX 5.1 on AIX 5.3

Answer (score 2):

The AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications contains a wide variety of software, including
Application Development - gcc, g++, gdb, rpm, cvs, automake, autoconf, libtool, bison, flex, gettext check the link

```
http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html
```